# Laravel move project from Ubuntu Server to Local XAMPP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, xampp

I have a Laravel project that I copied from my Ubuntu server and now I am trying to run it my local machine (XAMPP on Mac) I have been struggling with this for a few days now and I feel like I am going insane.

When I paste my project in XAMPP htdocs folder I get this error:

> View [welcome] not found

Which `php artisan cache:clear` makes that go away, then I get this error:

> The bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable

Then I do this, `php artisan cache:clear` which gives me a new error:

> Class view does not exist

Then after that no matter what I do either in terminal or viewing the web browser, I always get the error

> Class view does not exist

Then I have tried `composer update` still the same error.....what am I doing wrong?

This has been a nightmare.

Comment: can you share more details on which system you are tryings its windows or mac ?

Comment: This is on a mac.

Comment: Use Laravel Valet. XAMPP sucks TBH.

Comment: Try deleting the `vendor` folder then run `composer install`

Comment: check `Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,` in `confi/app.php`

Comment: php artisan config:clear try that. also, don't forget you need to access the public folder of laravel root folder

Comment: try `php artisan view:clear `

Comment: Could you share the config settings of XAMP?

Comment: @IbrahimShendy I deleted the vendor folder and did composer install, now I get this error: `The bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable.` Then I did `sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap` and got the same error back `View [welcome] not found`

Comment: @user979331 well that's a different error now. How about changing the view directory permissions? `resources/view/` , may be the `resources` too

Comment: I tried that, did not work

Comment: @user979331 Try: `php artisan config:clear`. Also if it didn't work, try this: `php artisan cache:clear` , `php artisan config:cache`. That may solve it.

Comment: run ```composer dumpautoload```

Comment: @user979331: Have you checked the contents of your `storage/framework/cache/data` and `storage/framework/view` to see if they are actually getting cleared by your artisan commands?

Comment: @user979331 Hey can you contact me [here](https://www.linkedin.com/in/rafay-hassan/) and share the project with me

Comment: Which Laravel version you're using? 5.3? 5.6? 5.3 I suppose. Each new version catch specific errors more precisely. Also check that your `.env` file has no value with space, and check your `config/app.php` file has no missing comma. There is so many reasons this can be created. Check this [Github Issue solutions](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18053) to see more reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last time i checked Laravel doesnt run on `XAMPP` but rather on the `PHP` installed when installing `XAMPP` so the project can be saved anywhere on the computer.

Given this being the fact, you will need to just have an active PHP installation and then you copy only the relevant files of the project onto the new computer (such files that you will get when you push your project onto `GitHub`). It doesn`t come with cache issues then all you need to do afterwards is to

```
php artisan key:generate
```

then `composer install` or `composer update` to get the vendor packages from online

My money right now is on picking the relevant files and reinstall with them
According to my own installation when changing the computer this is the list you will have to copy
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I just tried to reproduce your issue on my mac. So i have installed XAMPP with the PHP version 7.1.25 which is the equivalent version of my local PHP version

So I installed the XAMPP and started server.

Downloaded my laravel project folder from my ubuntu server and copied it to htdocs (XAMPP)

When i tried to run **http://localhost/myproject/public** it shows the exception like

```
There is no existing directory at "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/myproject/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied
```

Then i gave full permission to the storage folder

```
chmod -R 777 storage
```

And changed ownership for the files inside myproject folder.

Here i just checked the ownership of the **dashboard** directory which is running perfectly and given the **same user ownership** of myproject directory.

```
chown -R root:admin .
```

Then following commands

```
composer install
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

After this my laravel code runs perfectly.

```
Class view does not exist
```

is probably a ownership issue of the directory

Comment: `chmod 777` may work, but *please* don't use it, or use it and asap change the permissions so not anyone have full control of files and folders

Comment: Since OP is looking for solution, I think he can use the `777`  for all the project directory. Then if it's really permission problem, he will change back to secure permission

Comment: I think the 777 talk is pointless as @KeitelDOG said. and moreover the OP is trying to move it to xampp, which is never recommended for production

Comment: @Shobi see my answer below and you will see secure way to set owner, group, read & write for them with `774` or `664`, `_www` for apache Mac, and `umask` setting, etc. I've been using proper files permission for over 5 years now. But since he is in development environment, he can just temporary pass to `777` just to make sure that his problem is not related to file permission.
And by the way he's moving it to Local Mac, so production does not apply here at all.

Answer (score 2):

For me (when developing on xampp, what I do for all my projects) - I'd not recommend to put your stuff in the htdocs folder. Laravel expects to not be hosted on a subfodler e.g. (localhost/my-project). So you should set up a virtual host in order to make it work easily (e.g. my-project.test) which is a bit annoying.

Simple solution is using the `php artisan serve` command in order to simply setup a local server on port 8000.

Don't forget to start xampp for the mysql server.

Some typical tips were already mentioned:

- delete vendor folder & run `composer install` (install composer if you haven't)
- run `composer dump-autoload`
- run `php artisan key:generate`
- ofcourse don't forget the migration `php artisan migrate`
- and clear your full cache `php artisan cache:clear`

Usually you do not need to set any file permissions afaik

Answer (score 1):

`chmod -R 777 storage/`

If you have a different user for apache2 (usually www-data), also do:

`chown -R www-data storage/`

You could also check if it runs with the built-in server:

`php artisan serve`

Comment: I got this error: chown: www-data: illegal user name

Comment: never use 777, it is extremely bad practice.

Comment: @RayA I know. He's only trying to get the app running locally, so having a 777 folder on localhost isn't a big deal. Instead of just saying "its bad practice", you could actually expand and explain to OP why it is bad practice. Cause it seems you just grep for answer that say '777' and copy/paste your "bad practice" comment for some upvotes

Comment: @eselskas, I can understand your frustration that I said it is a bad practice, and for your knowledge, I didn't copy/paste it, but for the sake of helping, here is why, 777 permission means each and every user can access, write, delete, update, the files contained in that directory without a problem, if malicious users gets access to that file, then he/she can upload any files and runs them, which will compromise the server security.

Answer (score 1):

You can create .htaccess file and add below data into .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

After create .htaccess file, set laravel root path in terminal and run below command in terminal

```
php artisan serve
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your Apache is already serving then you have permission problems only. And since you're using Mac, the default user name and group in Apache conf is `_www` for Mac and not `www-data` that is for Ubuntu. You can see it in the `httpd.conf` file :

```
<IfModule unixd_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User _www
Group _www

</IfModule>
```

Now, use terminal, get in your project directory let's say `cd /var/www/laravel-project1` and make sure that the group `_www` (or the user too in some case of your App environment logic` has access (read and write) to :

All public directory and sub-directories containing assets if you have.

```
sudo chgrp -R _www public
sudo chmod -R 774 public
```

Storage directory and sub-directories specified here (`storage/framework` -> all, `storage/logs` -> all, `storage/app` -> `public` directory only), and bootstrap/cache directory and files

```
sudo chgrp -R _www storage/framework storage/logs storage/app/public bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R 774 storage/framework storage/logs storage/app/public bootstrap/cache
```

That should get rid of all of your permissions problem to access pages.

BUT now if on using the page, sessions and logs files that are created you get other problems, there might be a last problem of permission which is called `UMask`, which tell Apache or Web Server like Nginx what permission to assign to newly created directory or files for the user `_www`. By default Apache `umask` is `0002`, which give `0775` for directory and `0664` for new file. If ever `umask` value was changed to `0022` like it's the default in Nginx, then the equivalent permissions `0755` or `0644` will not be sufficient for your Apache group `_www` to write in the directories that have group `_www`. So you can either change `umask` to `0002` or change owner to `_www` :

```
sudo chown -R _www public storage/framework storage/logs storage/app/public
```

So that depends on your configs.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem as you, but not moving from ubuntu to mac, it was from windows to linux, I was in a total mess, but only git rescued me, it might give you a bit of pain, but it is going to save you in the future.
Here is the steps you need to do.

1. Create empty repository on the mac using this command `git init --bare`.
2. Clone the repository to the ubuntu using `git clone`.
3. Copy your laravel code to the clone you made in step 2.
4. Push the files from the ubuntu to the MAC.
5. Test the project.

The directory you will create in the mac, it can be inside the htdocs of the xammp.
I know it might be painful task to do, but it is quite worth it.

Sources for more information:
[git-scm](https://git-scm.com)
[Getting Git on Server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server)

If you need more help, I'll be more than happy to discuss it with you.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: The following works for Laravel 5.x but also 4.2, not tested with other versions*

Why not using Git?
(If you are not familiar with it, have a look at [the official website](https://git-scm.com/), there are also tons of tutorials on the web)

Usually, copy-pasting entire projects is not a good idea, because of some file/directory permissions and other not-so-good stuff.

That's what I did to move my project from Windows to my Ubuntu Server:

- Put your project on a git repository (GitHub, GitLab, or whatever), the .gitignore files provided with the Laravel apps are, in most cases, good enough
- On your new machine, clone your repository
- Do a

  ```
  composer dump-autoload
  composer install
  ```
- To migrate your db, do

  ```
  php artisan migrate
  ```

  and if you have seeding, do this

  ```
  php artisan db:seed
  ```

Then, if you have problem with file/folder permissions, do not **EVER** do a `chmod -R 777 path/`, if you have to do this to solve your problem, you are doing something wrong.
This command grants all privileges to anyone to all the files and folders in the `path` folder.

In your case, you have to do the following:

- First, find which username is apache using to run the server (usually it's www-data)

  ```
  ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'
  ```
- Then, change the project directory owner to apache's user (example for www-data apache user)

  ```
  sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/htdocs/your-project/
  ```
- Set folders permissions

  ```
  sudo find /var/htdocs/your-project/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
  ```
- Set files permissions

  ```
  sudo find /var/htdocs/your-project/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
  ```
- To fix the bootstrap/cache and storage/ permission problem, do

  ```
  sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/htdocs/your-project/
  ```

**Laravel 5.x**

```
    sudo chmod -R ug+rwx /var/htdocs/your-project/storage /var/htdocs/your-project/bootstrap/cache
```

**Laravel 4.2**

```
    sudo chmod -R ug+rwx /var/htdocs/your-project/storage /var/htdocs/your-project/app/bootstrap/cache
```

Then, you should be good.

Doing that way, you can easily move your project from a machine to another without struggling with permission fixes or anything.

More info and source for files and folders permissions command-line instructions, see [Laravel 5 Files Folders Permission and Ownership Setup](https://www.itechempires.com/2017/06/laravel-5-files-folders-permission-ownership-setup/)

Answer (score 0):

**Go to your project folder add run these commands from terminal**

> sudo chmod -R 777 your_projrct/storage
>
> sudo chmod -R 777 your_projrct/bootstrap/cache
>
> sudo chown -R :www-data your_project
>
> sudo chmod -R g+s your_project

then **`php artisan key:generate`** and **`composer install`**

Comment: Never **EVER** use chmod 777, it's a huge security breach

Comment: @Amaury for read/write on storage and cache folder need to give 777 permission. have any other way?

Comment: For all folders inside storage/ you need to set the owner to your apache user and then give that user (instead of anyone) write permissions on files, ie: 644. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53766229/6505285) for more details

Answer (score 0):

when user/group `www-data` are unkown; most Linux distributions use `apache`:

```
chown -R apache:apache dirname
```

while on `OSX`, this would be user/group `_www`:

```
chown -R _www:_www dirname
```

adding the current user to group `_www` might make life easier, in general.

Answer (score 0):

To isolate your issues:

1. Get your code into a repository(bitbucket or github)
2. Clone the repository into your local environment
3. Run `composer install`
4. Run `php artisan serve`. This way you rule out xampp as an issue.
5. In your browser go to `localhost:8000`

If you already have your entire codebase on your local box(including the vendor folder) then skip steps 1 and 2. Step 3 wouldn't hurt, but you can probably skip that too.

Once you get everything working, switch to xampp.

Answer (score 0):

## First of all:

```
composer update
composer dumpautoload
php artisan cache:clear
```

And then just configure a virtual host

## 1. Create a local domain for your app

Edit `hosts` file and redirect all requests from your domain to `127.0.0.1`:

```
127.0.0.1   lara.vel
```

## 2. Configure a Virtual Host

Edit \xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost lara.vel:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public"
  ServerAdmin laravel.dev
  <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Done! Open up your domain in your browser, You'll see your project there!

---

The other way is simple, Just run `artisan serve`.

> Please vote up if you found this answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you copied the project from Ubuntu so it is a permissions problem.

first get users on your Mac machine by typing this in terminal

```
users
```

then copy the user you just got for example (username) and use it in this command

```
sudo chown -R username project-directory
```

then check for `yourproject-directory/bootstrap/cache`  if it not exists, go create it. else run this command:

```
sudo chmod -R guo+w project-directory/bootstrap/cache
```

then

```
sudo chmod -R guo+w project-directory/storage
```

then clear composer autoload and cache and config using artisan command

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

now try to run the project if the problem still exists,
you need to check `config/app.php` if it contains `Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class`
the view service provider.

if it is not there, so add it